# Lavasfy client is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm working on a music bot project, the error said `LavasfyClient is not a constructor`, the code was scrapped because I switch from `erela.js-spotify` to `lavasfy`, I don't know what I do wrong and I've read the documentation of `lavasfy`.

Some parts might be empty because I delete them (like `clientID`, lavalink host, password, etc)

Here's my code:

```
    Manager
  } = require("erela.js"),
  
    LavasfyClient = require("lavasfy"),
    Deezer = require("erela.js-deezer"),
    Facebook = require("erela.js-facebook"),
    config = require(`${process.cwd()}/botconfig/config.json`),
    clientID = process.env.clientID || config.spotify.clientID,
    clientSecret = process.env.clientSecret || config.spotify.clientSecret;
  module.exports = (client) => {
      if (!clientID || !clientSecret || clientID.length < 5 || clientSecret.length < 5) {
        client.manager = new Manager({
      plugins: [
        new Deezer(),
        new Facebook(),
      ],
          send(id, payload) {
            var guild = client.guilds.cache.get(id);
            if (guild) guild.shard.send(payload);
          },
        });
      } else {
        client.manager = new Manager({
          nodes: collect(config.clientsettings.nodes),
          plugins: [
            new LavasfyClient({
              clientID: "",
              clientSecret: "",
            }),
          ],
          send(id, payload) {
            var guild = client.guilds.cache.get(id);
            if (guild) guild.shard.send(payload);
          },
        });
      }
      //require the other events
      require("./node_events")(client)
      require("./client_events")(client)
      require("./events")(client)
      require("./musicsystem")(client)
      
  };
  

  function collect(node) {
    return node.map(x => {
        
      if (!x.host) throw new RangeError('"host" must be provided');
      if (!x.password) throw new RangeError('"password" must be provided');
      if (typeof x.port !== 'number') throw new RangeError('"port" must be a number');
      if (x.retryAmount && typeof x.retryAmount !== 'number') throw new RangeError('Retry amount must be a number');
      if (x.retryDelay && typeof x.retryDelay !== 'number') throw new RangeError('Retry delay must be a number');
      if (x.secure && typeof x.secure !== 'boolean') throw new RangeError('Secure must be a boolean');

      return {
          host: x.host ? x.host : '',
          password: x.password ? x.password : '',
          port: x.port && !isNaN(x.port) ? Number(x.port) : 443,
          identifier: x.identifier || x.host,
          retryAmount: x.retryAmount ? Number(x.retryAmount) : 5,
          retryDelay: x.retryDelay ? Number(x.retryDelay) : 5000,
          secure: x.secure ? x.secure : false
      };
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you had a chance to check out my answer below? Did it solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

`LavasfyClient` is not a default export. You need to destructure it like this:

```js
const { LavasfyClient } = require("lavasfy");

// ...
// ...
// ...

plugins: [
  new LavasfyClient({
    clientID: "",
    clientSecret: "",
  }),
],
```